# SQL : Creating View using MAX() + SUM() with 3 related tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, I have a view contains 3 related tables. (Material , Order, OrderDetail)

Each "Order" contains several "OrderDetail"，and each "OrderDetail" contain 1 "Material".

```
Table Material
----------------------------
MaterialID      MaterialName
    1               egg
    2               flour
    3               butter
```

```
Table Order
----------------------------
OrderID               Date
    1              2019-1-01
    2             2019-12-12
    3              2019-6-06
```

```
Table OrderDetail
----------------------------
DetailID         OrderID       MaterialID     Price     Quantity    Total
    1                1             1             10       5           50 
    2                1             2            100       5          500 

    3                2             2            200       4          800    
    4                2             3           2000       4         8000

    5                3             3           1000       3         3000
    6                3             1             20       3           60
```

This is the original view i created

```
View Original 
----------------------------
MaterialID         OrderID         Date       Price        Total
    1                1         2019-1-01         10           50 
    1                3         2019-6-06         20           60 

    2                1         2019-1-01        100          500    
    2                2        2019-12-12        200          800

    3                2        2019-12-12       2000         8000
    3                3         2019-6-06       1000         3000
```

Now what I want it to find "Latest Price" (which bind with "Latest Date") and "Sum" (overall money I spend on EACH material)

```
View Edit 
----------------------------
MaterialID       OrderID     LatestDate      LatestPrice      Sum           
    1              3         2019-6-06           20           110

    2              2        2019-12-12          200          1300 

    3              2        2019-12-12         2000         11100
```

I know how to filter each column individually with Max(Date) Max(Price) Sum(total) Group By, but I am still unfamiliar with Subquery, INNER join, and other techniques.

Thank you for your time. I've tried to illustrate the problem the best I can, if any additional info is needed please ask anytime :).

Comment: Are you sure that's your original SQL, or that you're using SQL Server? `ORDER` is a reserved word in SQL Server so syntax like `INNER JOIN Order ON` and `Order.OrderID` will cause an error.

Comment: @Larnu Im using Sql server, it contains dbo. on each table but i remove them for clearer view

Comment: @Larnu Im OK if the view is not in ORDER, I can sort it later in C#.

Comment: That doesn't change my point that if an object has a name that is a reserved keyword then you can't reference the name without quoting it. `SELECT * FROM dbo.Order;` would also fail. Provided valid SQL is really important, as otherwise your code is going to be questioned if you say it works

Comment: @Larnu Thank you, i removed the view code. Sorry for causing the confusion :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT 
    m.MaterialID, od.OrderID, o.Date, 
    od.Price, od.Total
  FROM Material m 
  INNER JOIN OrderDetail od ON m.MaterialID = od.MaterialID 
  INNER JOIN [Order] o ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID
)

SELECT 
    c.MaterialID, c.OrderID, c.Date LatestDate, 
    c.Price LatestPrice, g.Sum
FROM CTE c INNER JOIN (
  SELECT MaterialID, MAX(Date) maxdate, SUM(Total) Sum
  FROM CTE
  GROUP BY MaterialID
) g ON g.MaterialID = c.MaterialID AND g.maxdate = c.Date 
ORDER BY c.MaterialID
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9a95e5db54a9031c586b7904888c8740).
Results:

```
> MaterialID | OrderID | LatestDate          | LatestPrice |  Sum
> ---------: | ------: | :------------------ | ----------: | ---:
>          1 |       3 | 06/06/2019 00:00:00 |          20 |  110
>          2 |       2 | 12/12/2019 00:00:00 |         200 | 1300
>          3 |       2 | 12/12/2019 00:00:00 |        2000 |11000
```

Comment: OMG, I'm terribly sorry. I miss type the "sum value". It should be the sum of all Total on each Material. Material 1 (50+60 = 110). I had just edit my post

Comment: I modified it to fit my database, and it works perfectly. Thank you for your time and the Demos u provide.

Answer (score 1):

This answers your original question using `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT m.MaterialID, od.OrderID, od.Date, od.Price, od.Total
FROM Material m CROSS APPLY JOIN
     (SELECT TOP (1) od.*, o.date
      FROM OrderDetail od INNER JOIN
           Orders o
           ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID
      WHERE m.MaterialID = od.MaterialID
      ORDER BY o.Date DESC
     ) od
ORDER BY m.MaterialID;
```

This answers your revised question using window functions:

```
SELECT MaterialID, oOrderID, Date, Price, Total, sum_total
FROM (SELECT m.MaterialID, od.OrderID, o.Date, 
             od.Price, od.Total,
             SUM(od.total) OVER (PARTITION BY m.MaterialId) as sum_total,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m.MaterialId ORDER BY o.Date DESC) as seqnum
      FROM Material m INNER JOIN
           OrderDetail od
           ON m.MaterialID = od.MaterialID INNER JOIN
           Orders o
           ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID
     ) mod
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY m.MaterialID;
```

Comment: I'm terribly sorry. I miss type the "sum value". It should be the sum of all Total on each Material. Material 1 (50+60 = 110)

Comment: @Max . . . I wondered why the column name changed.  The changed the second query to include the sum.

Comment: The "view code" is the code from my sql server, but the names of the tables and their columns are simplified by me. My initial intent is to simplified it so is more readable. @Larnu has warn me on this so i delete the view code. I really sorry for causing the confusion.

Comment: "CROSS APPLY"  "ROW_NUMBER()" "PARTITION BY" all vocabularies to me, Ill need time to to digest it. Thank you again for your answers.

Comment: @Max . . . Windows functions are quite powerful and more efficient than alternative methods for this problem.  This is a better solution than repeating a CTE.